# Laravel NotFoundHttpException although route exists

Tags: php, ajax, rest, laravel, eloquent

I use vue.js and Laravel 5.1 to create a little file sharing application.

Everything works perfect but now I wanted to make sure the owner of each file is able to remove users from his file (he had to share the file with those users at first of course), therefore I make a PUT request to an URL called `/files/share`.

My Laravel route looks like this:

```
Route::put('/files/share', 'FileController@test');
```

When I run `php artisan route:list` it gets listed as well.

The client-side code looks like this:

```
this.$http.put('/files/share', { some_data }, function(data) {
    if(data.error){
        this.$set('error', data.error);
    } else {
        this.$set('file', data);
    }
});
```

The exact error that I get is this:

```
2/2 NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 46:
No query results for model [App\File].
1/2 ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 129:
No query results for model [App\File].
```

But the Application doesn't even get to the controller, if I just return something from there the error is the same.

Comment: You probably have a conflicting route. Something like `/files/{file}`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I have a resource for `/files` and the `FileController`, I've been checking the server logs and everything but not the most obvious things :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Laravel routes, the order matters. Routes with dynamic segments like `files/{file}` or resource routes should always be defined *after* the ones that are static. Otherwise Laravel will interpret the `share` part in your URL as ID.

So, as you've figured out yourself you simply need to change the order of your routes:

```
Route::put('/files/share', 'FileController@test');
Route::resource('/files', 'FileController');
```

Comment: Thanks once again, I already knew about this but unfortunately the error message confused me and I checked everything except the simplest and right solution.

Comment: Thank you @lukasgeiter it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) I checked my routes once more and had to define the /files/share route before my RESTful resource route.