# Laravel NotFoundHttpException although route exits

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I added a new route as:

```
Route::post('friendSend/{uid}','FriendController@sendFriendRequest')->name('friends.add');
```

and called it as a  hyperlink to submit form:

```
<a href="{{route('friends.add',$user->uid)}}"
                      onclick="event.preventDefault();
                               document.getElementById('addfriend-form).submit();">
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video" style="color:#F44336;"></i> Add Friend
</a>

<form action="{{route('friends.add',$user->uid)}}" method="post" id="addfriend-form">
                 {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

However when I click on the said link, I get redirected to /friendSend with the said error.

the route is visible in:

```
php artisan route:list
```

which makes sense since I called it via it's name 'friends.add'. It doesn't even go the controller.

I've already tried the following:

[Laravel NotFoundHttpException although route exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271008/laravel-notfoundhttpexception-although-route-exists)

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Friend;
use Auth;

class FriendController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
   $this->middleware('auth');
 }

 public function index()
 {
    return redirect()->route('home');
 }

 public function sendFriendRequest($id)
 {
   echo "hello world";
 }
}
```

**Update:**

Manually entering the url as /friendSend/2 (or any number for that matter) works.

Comment: Controller code?

Comment: Are you using findOrFail() in your controller? If so that throws a 404, please post your controller.

Comment: idk why it would matter but to debug this, FriendController@sendFriendRequest only contains an echo statement.

Comment: added controller.

Comment: so I don't get the error if I do this manually friendSend/2

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081841/how-to-redirect-to-a-route-in-laravel-5-by-using-href-tag-if-iam-not-using-blade

Comment: I'm sure that you have something else wrong in your code, but you did not provided it here.

Comment: If you are trying to post to a form, why do you have a link with an href? I think your error is bc it is trying to do a GET while you have defined a POST, but I'm not entirely sure bc u seem to be preventing the href anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `'` in the `onclick` javascript.

```
<a href="{{route('friends.add',$user->uid)}}"
                      onclick="event.preventDefault();
                               document.getElementById('addfriend-form').submit();">
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video" style="color:#F44336;"></i> Add Friend
</a>

<form action="{{route('friends.add',$user->uid)}}" method="post" id="addfriend-form">
                 {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

If this doesn't work, what is the href on the generated page? Do you have multiple of these forms on a single page?

Comment: ah this probably happened whilst posting the question, the ' isn't a issue in the code and no, I don't have multiple of these forms on a single page.

Comment: @Siddhant What is the href that is on the page after blade has generated the url?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are doing wrong on set the url in form submit.You are adding route like

```
href="{{route('friends.add',$user->uid)}}"
```

Just modified it as

```
href="{{route('friends.add',['uid' => $user->uid])}}"
```

You can refer [Laravel Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes)